# How to plot a vector field with colormap in gnuplot?

Tags: dictionary, vector, colors, field, gnuplot

I have data in a text file in the following way

```
x  y  dx dy z
1  0  1  2  5
2  3  3  3  6
2  4  5  4  8
.  .  .  .  .
```

I'm using gnuplot and I can already plot the vector field using columns x,y,dx,dy but I also want to plot color map using x,y and z on the same graph. I want something like this [vector field with color map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjWJr.jpg)

I have no idea how to do this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `plot 'data' with image`. You can look up the plotting styles in the [gnuplot doc](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf).

Then you can combine your vector plot and this one. Examples with source code you can find here: [image «  Gnuplotting](http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/image/). This way you should be able to create graphs like the desired one:

```
#your plot script without plot...
plot 'data' u 1:2:5 with image, \ # not scaled yet
     '' u 1:2:3:4 with vector ...#your vector field plot
```

Note: Thies does only works, if you have your data in the form of

```
1 1 z1
1 2 z2
. . ..
1 n zn
2 1 z21
2 2 z22
. . ...
2 n z2n
3 1 ...
. . ...
```

So you need ALL datapoints without a 'hole' in it...

I'll continue tomorrow...

Comment: It says "Matrix does not represent a grid"

Comment: Forget the matrix thing, you don't need it here, sorry.

Comment: Thank you. Now, it's working, but can you tell a way to smoothen (or interpolate) the edges between different color regions?